# Bind mounts within bind mounts

Tags: linux, bind-mount

I am trying to bind mount one file over another file, then remove the file that is now hidden from access. I'm trying to go about this as follows:

```
folder1# echo a > a
folder1# echo b > b
folder1# mount -o bind a b
folder1# cat b
a #All good - the bind mount worked
folder1# cd ..
# mount -o bind folder1 folder2
# cd folder2
folder2# cat b
b #OK, as expected
folder2# unlink b
rm: cannot remove 'b': Device or resource busy
```

I want to delete `b` from the actual disk, but leave the bindmount from `a` active.

So if it worked, it would go like

```
# cd folder2
folder2# cat b
b
folder2# unlink b
folder2# cat b
cat: error: No such file or directory
folder2# cd ../folder1
folder1# cat b
a #The bind mount is still active
```

How can I make Linux behave how I want?

Comment: Simplest way is write your own filesystem that allows that behavior.

Comment: @stark Unfortunately not an option; it needs to work on android (rooted of course), and some devices are really messed up and don't allow installation of unsigned kernel modules

Comment: Actually, it looks to be dependent on kernel version: https://lwn.net/Articles/570338/

Comment: @stark 3.13... I'm running 4.9 on my PC and still seeing this behaviour.